# Url encode in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, urlencode, node-modules

I have a nodejs piece of code where am trying to do a db.get to cloudant trying to build the URL.

```
var contactsFile = result.docs[0]._id;
var finalUrl = contactsFile+'/'+contactsFile;
testDb.get(urlencode.decode(finalUrl), function(err, data) {
     if (!err) {

                    abc = data;
                    console.log("file" , abc);

                }

                else{
                    console.log("this is the error " , err);
                }
            });
```

When i try to print the URL that is passed the get request, the URL is passed as
https://cloudant/db/contactsFile%2FcontactsFile.

But I want to pass it as https://cloudant/db/contactsFile/contactsFile.

I have tried uriencode and decode and tried what i understood, but when i print with urlencode.decode it shows /  and in the get request no matter wat i do it gets converted to %2F.

This might be a simple question but as I am new to node I am still learning.

Comment: Why are you decoding the URL? Just do `testDb.get(finalUrl, ...`?

Comment: I did.. that gave me the same result too

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you are now passing "https://cloudant/db/contactsFile%2FcontactsFile" to your testDb.get, but you'd need to pass "https://cloudant/db/contactsFile/contactsFile".

If that's so you could try this:

```
testDb.get(decodeURIComponent(finalUrl), ...);
```

For further reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: I tried that too.. still passes "https://cloudant/db/contactsFile%2FcontactsFile"